# Apache Kafka - Producer - Idempotence beetween producers message

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api, idempotent

We have microservice architecture on our project. There is a microservice where  scheduler trigger logic of sending message to Kafka.  The problem is that if there are more than one microservice instances, then each of them will send a message to Kafka. How can achieve idempotency between all producers?  I mean that if 'equal' messages will be sent to Kafka with various producers, when it will be committed in log only once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Producers are independent.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24289039)

Comment: @Adrian "You can't do that" *sure can* be an answer to the question

Comment: I completely and utterly disagree. "How can I do X with Y". "You can't, Y doesn't support doing X". That is clearly an answer to the question.